# angular number-only directive accepting two decimals (0..)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I've create a directive for accepting only numbers and numbers with deicmals. My code is

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[number-only]'
})
export class NumberOnlyDirective {
    // Allow decimal numbers and negative values
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.){0,1}([0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
    // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
    // Backspace, tab, end, home
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "Delete"];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using this directive as

```
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" number-only />
```

Problem is that this input element accepts two decimals like this **5..35**.
I've tested the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/3BNaXE/1). It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx: (/^\d*.?\d{0,2}$/g)